# How to limit the characters under data-bind="text:

Tags: laravel, data-binding, limit

I want to add an limit of 120 characters to this code:

```
<p data-bind="text: plot"></p>
```

I use laravel

Comment: You mean the content of the paragraph `p` should not be more than 120 characters?

Comment: Yes, this is correct - no more that 120